# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I am getting following error after adding `"libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar"` jar.

> Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/analytics/containertag/common/FunctionType;
>
> Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple
>   dex files define
>   Lcom/google/analytics/containertag/common/FunctionType;

I know `"Multiple dex files"` problem have been answered several times but solutions are not working for me.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you might want to let others know which existing solutions you've tried and not working.. so others might have more clue about what kind of other problem is happening there

Comment: Are you having `googleplayservices` library project in your dependency list as well as `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar` in you dependencies list?

Comment: @Nitin Misra,yes I do have googleplayservices library..

Comment: then please remove jar of `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar`

and use google Analytics from these import defined in `googleplayservices` library project
`import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;`

Comment: Your solution has fixed the problem.